# Default value V/s passing value in INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using MSSQL SERVER. The questions I am asking might be silly but I want some valid answers. So here is my question:

I have a table with some columns. I have taken default in some column like `0 (for INT column)`, `GETDATE() (for DATE column)`. Now one of my colleague said that taking `Getdate()` as default will increase overhead so better to pass datetime by INSERT statement. Is it true?

Is it not applicable to 0 or 1 (for INT column)? 
How does it create overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int default 0 or 1 is a value like hardcode.

but, getdate () like function to know the date on the computer server of SQL Server.

so, when the insert statement, the column with the default getdate () will look for the value prior to the server computer before the command insert is run.